# How can I export an evernote account into Emacs.org?

Tags: emacs, evernote

I am currently using evernote but I have since moved to emacs for many tasks so I would like to access everything from emacs. How can I move all my evernote data to emacs-org mode?

Comment: I doubt there is a premade package for exporting evernote to the org-mode format. But emacs org-mode is very simple, so it should be possible to write a simple script to read an evernote entry and produce an org entry from it. Is it possible to export from evernote? What does an evernote entry look like as a text file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably already found an answer, but if not there is [Evernote mode for Emacs](http://code.google.com/p/emacs-evernote-mode/) (requires Ruby 1.8.7 or later).

Answer (score 3):

1. Apply for Evernote API key
2. Download and run the backup script in http://norman.walsh.name/2009/11/01/evernote
3. Write another Python script to convert that to org mode files.

Comment: Additionally the local Evernote database is a SQLite file.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem myself and wrote a tool to solve it: https://github.com/jkarres/enex2org.

From the README:

## enex2org

Tool to convert Evernote export files into orgmode.

### What does it do?

It converts your Evernote export file into an orgmode file and also extracts out
your attachments, saving them as orgmode attachments.  (Use C-c C-a to see your
attachments.)

Notes that were created with a source URL (e.g., created using the web clipper)
are presumed to have relatively complicated formatting and so are saved as html
files (with links in the org file).

Notes without a source URL are presumed to have been written manually and so
are converted into orgmode formatting.